# local variable 'formulario' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, formularios

Tengo entendido que el problema esta el la linea que dice "if formulario.is_valid():" ya que los identificadores no son iguales y por ende Django toma a formulario como dos variables distintas pero sigo sin solucionarlo.

```
def create_full_article(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        formualario = FormArticle(request.POST)

        if formulario.is_valid():
            
            data_form = formulario.cleaned_data

            title = data_form['title']
            content = data_form['content']
            public =  data_form['public']

            articulo = Article(
                title = title,
                content = content,
                public = public
            )


            articulo.save()

            return redirect ('articulos')

    else:    

        formulario = FormArticle()

    return render(request, 'create_full_article.html',{'form': formulario})
```

Comment: Hola asignaste el valor en post a **formualario**  y contiene UA debiendo ser sólo U y más abajo tratas de usar formulario, bien escrito, y obviamente no ha sido creada la variable.

Comment: Como seria solo U y no UA. Gracias

Comment: escribiste `formualario = FormArticle(request.POST)` fijate en que lleva **ua** y en la línea siguiente dice `if formulario.is_valid():` sin **ua** sólo la u, fde modo que formulario no ha sido asignado. Normalmente uno lee lo que espera ver y no lo que está escrito por eso pasas por encima del error tipográfico

Comment: Muchas gracias no podía ver el error tipográfico.